# Database returns null after successful connection with Devart in C#

Tags: c#, devart, interbase

I am trying to connect C# to an InterBase Database. I have downloaded and install Devart ODBC Driver for Windows and installed it. I configured the System DSN in control panel and got a Success message when I tested the connection. I generated a connection string during the process of configuring the driver which I am using to establish connection to the InterBase Database. I have managed to connect to the database in C# and also in PHP but if I try to query the database I get an error. If I display the connection information, the database name returns a null and I am suspecting that this is where the problem is but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cgKXyStXtFSvZHCxmEu79RZ9mHIcbi2l/view?usp=sharing) to my Devart ODBC configuration. My code in C# is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            string connString = "DRIVER=Devart ODBC Driver for InterBase;Description=testing;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Database=C:\\Program Files\\Embarcadero\\Databases\\TEST.GDB;Port=3051;User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey";
            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);

            try {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Information:\t");
                Console.WriteLine("\nConnection String:\t" +
                                  conn.ConnectionString);
                Console.WriteLine("\nConnection Timeout:\t" +
                                  conn.ConnectionTimeout);
                Console.WriteLine("\nDatabase:\t" +
                                  conn.Database);
                Console.WriteLine("\nDataSource:\t" +
                                  conn.DataSource);
                Console.WriteLine("\nDriver:\t" +
                                  conn.Driver);
                Console.WriteLine("\nServerVersion:\t" +
                                  conn.ServerVersion);
            }
            catch (OdbcException ex){
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
}
```

The above code is giving me [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rJ0mkU79aMkmbQXA_r0pV1PsnNPfMCjt/view?usp=sharing) output.

If I try to do a SELECT query on my 'USER' table in the database this is the error i get:

> > USERn unknown - line 1, char 15(0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [Devart][ODBC][InterBase]Dynamic SQL Error
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
> >        at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\C#\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 38

But if I enter a table name that does not exist in the database e.g. USR this is what i get:

> > USRle unknowne = -204Exception (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [Devart][ODBC][InterBase]Dynamic SQL Error
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> >        at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
> >        at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\C#\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 38

Comment: show us the `SELECT query on my 'USER' table`

Comment: `Driver={INTERSOLV InterBase ODBC Driver (*.gdb)};Server=localhost;
Database=localhost:C:\mydatabase.gdb;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

Comment: @JohnB the query is as follows:

`using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM USER", conn)) {

                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
                        while (reader.Read()) {
                            string word = reader.GetString(0);
                            Console.WriteLine(word);
                            // Word is from the database. Do something with it.
                        }
                    }
                }
`

Comment: might be permissions related? can you get data from any tables at all?

Comment: If I run the following query in PHP
` $SQLQuery = "SELECT USERNAME FROM user";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $SQLQuery);`

I get the following error:
`Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Devart][ODBC][InterBase]Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, char 22 user, SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect`

Comment: No I can't get data from any tables at all @JohnB.

Comment: is it case sensitive on the col/table names?

Comment: I can't seem to find anywhere to download the intersolv driver @ChetanRanpariya. Let me keep looking for it. I'll give you feedback once I find it.

Comment: No it is not case sensitive

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with my USER table. I just created a new table using a query and I ran a SELECT query on that new table and got a result but still can't get anything from USER